# Split string after every 2 words and store into list

Tags: java, arrays

I have a string of words as follows:

```
String words = "disaster kill people action scary seriously world murder loose world";
```

Now, I wish to split every 2 words and store them into a list so that it will produce something like:

```
[disaster kill, people action, scary seriously,...]
```

The problem with my code is that it will split whenever it encounters a space. How do I modify it so that it will only be added into the list if it only encounters every 2nd space, preserving the space after each word)

My code:

```
ArrayList<String> wordArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
     for(String word : joined.split(" ")) {
         wordArrayList.add(word);
     }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using [`String.split(String regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)?

Comment: OK...you can use something like: `words.split("(?<!\\G\\S+)\\s");`. I've used this before...it's well tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regular expression: `(?<!\\G\\S+)\\s`.

**PROOF:**

```
String words = "disaster kill people action scary seriously world murder loose world";
String[] result = words.split("(?<!\\G\\S+)\\s");

System.out.printf("%s%n", Arrays.toString(result));
```

And the result:

```
[disaster kill, people action, scary seriously, world murder, loose world]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop should leave you with an `ArrayList<String>` that has each word, right? All you need to do now is iterate through that list and combine words together in sets of twos.

```
ArrayList<String> finalList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < wordArrayList.Size(); i+=2) {

 if (i + 1 < wordArrayList.Size()
  finalList.add(wordArrayList.get(i) + " " + wordArrayList.get(i + 1);

}
```

This should take your split words and add them to the list with spaces so that they look like your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for splitting a string after 'n' words.
So I modify the above solution.

```
private void spiltParagraph(int splitAfterWords, String someLargeText) {
        String[] para = someLargeText.split(" ");
       ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < para.length; i += splitAfterWords) {
            if (i + (splitAfterWords - 1) < para.length) {
                StringBuilder compiledString = new StringBuilder();
                for (int f = i; f <= i + (splitAfterWords - 1); f++) {
                    compiledString.append(para[f] + " ");
                }
                data.add(compiledString.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into this problem today, adding an extra difficulty that is to write this solution in Scala. So, I needed to write a recursive solution that looks like:

```scala
val stringToSplit = "THIS IS A STRING THAT WE NEED TO SPLIT EVERY 2 WORDS"

@tailrec
def obtainCombinations(
    value: String,
    elements: List[String],
    res: List[String]
): List[String] = {
  if (elements.isEmpty)
    res
  else
    obtainCombinations(elements.head, elements.tail, res :+ value + ' ' + elements.head)
}

obtainCombinations(
  stringToSplit.split(' ').head,
  stringToSplit.split(' ').toList.tail,
  List.empty
)
```

The output will be:

```scala
res0: List[String] = List(THIS IS, IS A, A STRING, STRING THAT, THAT WE, WE NEED, NEED TO, TO SPLIT, SPLIT EVERY, EVERY 2, 2 WORDS)
```

Porting this to Java would be:

```java
String stringToSplit = "THIS IS A STRING THAT WE NEED TO SPLIT EVERY 2 WORDS";

public ArrayList<String> obtainCombinations(String value, List<String> elements, ArrayList<String> res) {
    if (elements.isEmpty()) {
        return res;
    } else {
        res.add(value + " " + elements.get(0));
        return obtainCombinations(elements.get(0), elements.subList(1, elements.size()), res);
    }
}

ArrayList<String> result =
        obtainCombinations(stringToSplit.split(" ")[0],
                Arrays.asList(stringToSplit.split(" ")),
                new ArrayList<>());
```